# How to sign for phonegap osx local build

Tags: ios, macos, cordova

I have just started out with osx to start deploying locally to my iphones.

I have NPM installed, I can create projects with no problem, however I can't deploy to my devices. O, also I have xcode installed.

```
Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/hutber/myapp/platforms/ios/build/device
    SDKROOT = iphoneos7.1
    VALID_ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64

Build settings from configuration file '/Users/hutber/myapp/platforms/ios/cordova/build.xcconfig':
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer

=== BUILD TARGET CordovaLib OF PROJECT CordovaLib WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

=== BUILD TARGET Sex Diaries OF PROJECT Sex Diaries WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No matching codesigning identity found: No codesigning identities     (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) matching “iPhone Developer” were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
Check dependencies
(1 failure)
```

Really no clue and I can't find anything in the documentation either...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to open the Xcode project in Xcode, and let it handle the signing (or at least point out what you're missing; you do have a developer account, right?).

In the platforms/ios directory, there should be an Xcode project file, which you can open from Xcode.  Note that any edits you make will be overwritten the next time you build for iOS from phonegap (it takes the common code & writes it to the various platforms), so you'd  still have to build the way you have before.

Comment: I have a dev account yes. Howevevr you can't open a phonegap project in xcode. At least this was my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Apple Developer Account (paid). You can't deploy app to the phone or .ipa file, just iOS Simulator.

Also try https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen